# When i deploy my Azure ARM Template it creates a storage, not an alert

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I created a Azure Template for an alert, because i want to upload the script (.json) with the new microservice  the same time. But if I deploy this .json file it creates a new storage, not an alert. I used the Powershell commands `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup -TemplateFile c:\MyTemplates\storage.json -storageAccountType Standard_GRS`. In my template i need to define the parameter `kind`, which is only acceptable with a value of `Storage` or `Blobstorage`, but i want non of these two. So how can i create an alert by using a script .json file and does anybody have a template, because MS isn't providing the correct one.

EDIT: Here is the .json file:

```
{
"$schema":
"http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01- 
01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"resources": [
{
  "name": "[concat('storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS"
  },
  "kind": "Storage",
  "id":
    "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageName",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "name": "tryAgain",
    "description": null,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "condition": {
      "$type":
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
      "odata.type":
        "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
      "dataSource": {
        "$type":
          "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type":
          "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
        "resourceUri":
          "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourcegroups/resourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.web/sites/name",
        "resourceLocation": null,
        "metricNamespace": null,
        "metricName": "AverageMemoryWorkingSet",
        "legacyResourceId": null
      },
      "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
      "threshold": 120000000,
      "windowSize": "PT10M",
      "timeAggregation": "Average"
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "$type":
          "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleWebhookAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type":
          "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
        "serviceUri":
          "Logic-app URL",
        "properties": {
          "$type":
            "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Common.Storage.CasePreservedDictionary`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Common.Storage",
          "logicAppResourceId":
            "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-WestEurope/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/Microsoft-Teams-Notifier"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any JSON code?

Comment: yes, i added the whole code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following reference for creating a metric alert via Azure Resource Manager template.  If you want to create a single ARM template which creates a storage account and then a metric alert to monitor the created storage account, you should make sure you have a dependsOn so that the alert rule is only created after the storage account.  The following document references the newer metric alerts, as opposed to the classic metric alerts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-metric-alerts-with-templates